# How to add library in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I tried 2 different adding 2 different API's to my project but I got the same error both.

I already added library to classpath but it gives the error.

[image: ERROR IMG]

I don't know if I did something wrong so here is another screen capture that shows how I added the JAR:

[image]

I tried compiling the library myself and adding it but it did not work either.

Comment: Hi why not use some build tool like maven which can handle dependencies for you? You can then load your project as a Maven Project in intellij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem you can try to do the following:

- Delete the .jar file from `Project Structure | Modules | forge-*** | Dependencies`
- Go to `Project Structure | Libraries`
- Click +, select the jar file and select the modules you want to add it to.
- Go to **PasteBin** class, point the cursor at Pastebin, press **Alt + Enter** and import the class.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html on how to manage libraries in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

Use maven or just add your library to the lib directory, also take a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/a/32853178/3631239

Comment: I followed the things i saw at "https://stackoverflow.com/a/32853178/3631239" but now it tells me to add "libs" to classpath. I think im typing the "dependencies" in the wrong place here is my "build.gradle": https://pastebin.com/zUc4gea5